# if statement gets run more than once in lua

Tags: if-statement, lua, fivem

hello once this event is triggered and checks the level and gives me the right reward the problem is that the xplayer.blablabla gets run random times more than once in 1 click anyone knows whats wrong ?

```
RegisterServerEvent('battlepass:rewardskteolekaramele')
AddEventHandler('battlepass:rewardskteolekaramele', function()
    local _source = source
    local xPlayer = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(source)
    local identifier = xPlayer.identifier
    MySQL.Async.fetchAll("SELECT level FROM levelxp_table WHERE identifier = @identifier", {
        ["identifier"] = GetPlayerIdentifiers(source)[1]},
        function(attributeti)
        print(attributeti[1].level)
        local resultar = attributeti[1].level
        if  attributeti[1].level == 1 or resultar == 11 or resultar == 21 or resultar == 31  or resultar == 41 or resultar == 51 or resultar == 61 or resultar == 71 or resultar == 81 or resultar == 91  then
            xPlayer.addMoney(50000)

        elseif  attributeti[1].level == 2 or resultar == 12 or resultar == 22 or resultar == 32 or resultar == 42 or resultar == 52 or resultar == 62 or resultar == 72 or resultar == 82 or resultar == 92   then
            xPlayer.addInventoryItem("WEAPON_FENNEC", 1)

            elseif  attributeti[1].level == 3 or resultar == 13 or resultar == 23 or  resultar == 33 or resultar == 43 or resultar == 53 or resultar == 63 or resultar == 73 or resultar == 83 or resultar == 93 then
            xPlayer.addAccountMoney('bitcoin_money', 10)



        end
    end)
    end)
```

Comment: More likely the event is triggered more than once. One reason could be that the function itself may lead eventually to a second event. Which can easily be tested by out-commenting code.

Comment: Thanks for answering that fast i have tried what you said still the same thing happens

Comment: That would have been easiest. With Developer Tools in the browser, Network, you can see the traffic. Some events like key events come more than once. Client side logging is possible.

Comment: thank you so much for your time sir have a nice day/night i fixed it by checking every level removing the or statement

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP fixed it already.

Comment: @Ynka if you were able to come to an answer post your solution too your own question and mark it. It is perfectly ok to self answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `if` statement that's being ran twice, it's the event.

I'm not sure exactly what this code does, as Lua isn't my main language, but I do have a bit of experience.

Try putting a `print("event ran")` at the start of the event. That way you'll be able to tell whether it's the `if` statement that's being ran twice or the actual event.